# Center of mass of a circular arc

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, circles

I have an infinitesimally thin wire in the shape of a circular arc, with uniform mass distribution. I would like to know the location of the center of mass of the wire.

The arc subtends an angle of 120° (one third of a full circle), and the radius is 3.

From the symmetry, I know that the center of mass is between the center of the circle, and the midpoint of the circular arc, but I do not know how to calculate the distance from the center of the circle to the center of mass.

I'm interested in the geometric aspects of the problem, not so much on the physical aspects of it.

Comment: What’s the linear mass density? What have you even tried?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: Should not matter, it is uniform density.

Comment: I am not sure what you gained by putting this question on hold when it already had three answers. What is off topic here, it is a mathematical question!!!

Comment: Read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Comment: @kpv, let me know if you disagree with my edit, and I'll revert it immediately.  This is the form of the question as I understood it (as a physicist, not a mathematician), with the final sentence added to explain why math and not physics. But, because I'm not a mathematician, other members here might disagree.  I found the question very useful (and derived the same solution as King Tut starting from an arbitrary 2D curve, infinitesimally thin with uniform mass distribution), and it seems useful to others, too. I like seeing both that and the proper, simple, geometric answer.

Comment: That said, you can make it purely geometric by replacing 'center of mass' with 'centroid', throughout. I hope another member here can help rewording the question that way! It'd be even better fit here that way.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Thanks a lot for your edit. It is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show the most general way to find the answer.

For a curve (or an infinitesimally thin wire with uniform density, i.e. uniform linear mass distribution), the center of mass is at the centroid of the curve.

In the general 2D case, the centroid of a parametric curve $\vec{s}(t) = \left ( x(t) , y(t) \right )$, $t_0 \le t \le t_1$ is at $( \hat{x} , \hat{y} )$,
$$\begin{cases}
\hat{x} = \frac{1}{L} \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} x(t) \, \delta(t) \, dt \\
\hat{y} = \frac{1}{L} \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} y(t) \, \delta(t) \, dt
\end{cases} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
where $\delta(t) \, dt$ is the arc length parameter at $t$,
$$\delta(t) \, dt = \sqrt{ \left( \frac{ d\, x(t) }{ d t } \right )^2 + \left( \frac{ d\, y(t) }{ d\, t} \right) ^2 } \, dt$$
and $L$ is the total length of the curve,
$$L = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \delta(t) \, dt$$

In this particular case, we have a circular arc,
$$\begin{cases}
x(\theta) = r \cos(\theta) \\
y(\theta) = r \sin(\theta)
\end{cases}$$
and therefore
$$\delta(\theta) \, d\theta = \sqrt{ \left(-r \sin(\theta)\right)^2 + \left(r \cos(\theta)\right)^2 } \, d\theta = \sqrt{ r^2 \left( (\sin\theta)^2 + (\cos\theta)^2 \right) } \, d\theta = \sqrt{ r^2 } \, d\theta = r \, d\theta$$
The arc distends one third of a full circle, or 120°. If we put the center of the circle at origin, and the midpoint of the arc on the positive $y$ axis, then $\theta$ ranges from $90°-120°/2 = 30°$ to $90°+120°/2 = 150°$, i.e. from $\theta = \pi/6$ radians to $\theta = 5 \pi/6$ radians.

The length $L$ of the circular arc we already know from geometry; it is one third of the perimeter of the circle of radius $r$,
$$L = \frac{2 \pi r}{3}$$

Substituting these to $\eqref{NA1}$ we get
$$\begin{cases}
\hat{x} = \frac{3}{2 \pi r} \displaystyle\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} r \cos(\theta) \, r \, d\theta \\
\hat{y} = \frac{3}{2 \pi r} \displaystyle\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} r \sin(\theta) \, r \, d\theta
\end{cases}$$
which simplify to
$$\begin{cases}
\hat{x} = \frac{3 r}{2 \pi} \displaystyle\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \cos(\theta) \, d\theta = \frac{3 r}{2 \pi} \left(\Bigl[-\sin\theta \Bigr]_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \right) \\
\hat{y} = \frac{3 r}{2 \pi} \displaystyle\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \sin(\theta) \, d\theta = \frac{3 r}{2 \pi} \left(\Bigl[\cos\theta \Bigr]_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \right)
\end{cases}$$
Because $-\sin(\pi/6) - -sin(5\pi/6) = 0$, $\hat{x} = 0$. Which is completely expected, because we arranged the arc to be symmetric around the $y$ axis.
Because $\cos(\pi / 6) - \cos(5\pi / 6) = \sqrt{3}/2 - -\sqrt{3}/2 = \sqrt{3}$,
$$\hat{y} = \frac{3 r}{2 \pi} \sqrt{3} = \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2 \pi} r$$

In the case of $r = 3$, $$\hat{y} = \frac{9 \sqrt{3}}{2 \pi} \approx 2.48$$

This is in perfect agreement with [King Tut's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622033/318422).

Comment: Thanks Again. Now, if it was a third of a sphere instead of a circle, would it still be 2.48? No need for another derivation, just Y/N will do. I think it should be same answer for a sphere (shell) as well

Comment: The sphere has a very different calculation. The answer turns out to be $\hat y = 2.25.$

Comment: @kpv: No, it would not. The idea is similar, if you consider the symmetries and use spherical coordinates; for example, $y(\theta) = r \cos(\theta)$ and $\delta(\theta) \, d\theta = r \sin(\theta) \, d\phi \, d\theta$, with $L$ now denoting the entire area, $\int r \sin(\theta) \, d\phi \, d\theta$. Note that both now involve a double integral, because we need to integrate over the area. Similar principle, but different calculation, and different result.

Answer (score 1):

General formula  of distance of com arc from centre of generating circle is $  \frac{\sin(\theta /2)}{\theta/2}R$ where $\theta$ is angle that arc subtends on centre of circle.  This result is proved using integration.

Using this you get answer as $ \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}R$

Comment: This is the same answer I derived, but it implies that the center of mass is situated outside of of the bounds of the arc

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: Outside of the bounds? Does not appear to be true per common sense. Is it really the case?

Comment: @King Tut, can I take the answer at face value, as the other two answers are slightly different.

Comment: @kpv: Yes, King Tut's answer is correct. For the full derivation from a general 2D curve with uniform mass distribution, see my overly complicated answer. I prefer this one, myself.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you the easiest way to calculate the centroid of a line of uniform mass. This can be expressed most easily in the complex plane as follows,

$$C=\frac{\int z~ds}{\int ds}=\frac{1}{L} \int z~ds=\frac{\int z~|\dot z|~d\theta}{\int |\dot z|~d\theta}$$

where $C$ is complex centroid, $L$ is the arc length, $\dot z$ is the derivative of $z$ w.r.t $\theta$. For a circular arc of radius r we then have

$$
z=re^{i\theta}\\
\dot z=ire^{i\theta}\\
|\dot z|=r
$$

then

$$
\begin{align}
C
&=\frac{r^2\int_{\theta1}^{\theta2}e^{i\theta}~d\theta}{r\int_{\theta1}^{\theta2}~d\theta}\\
&=r\frac{-i\left(e^{i\theta_2}-e^{i\theta_1} \right)}{\theta_2-\theta_1}
\end{align}
$$

Specializing to your case, with $\theta\in[0,2\pi/3]$ we find

$$C=r\frac{\sqrt{3}/2+i\cdot 3/2}{2\pi/3}$$

and, the radial distance to the centroid is given by

$$|C|=r\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}$$

as you already know. As for this not being on the curve, of course it cannot be. Imagine that the curve is on a massless plane. Where would suspend the plane from a string so that it did not tilt?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I have tried, assuming that the mass distribution along the length of the arc is uniform.**

$$\lambda=\frac{dm}{ds}=\frac{M}{L}$$
$$s=r\theta$$

Position your arc so that it is symmetrical about the $y$-axis and centered at the origin. Set the center of mass at $(h,k)$.

Due to symmetry about the $y$-axis, $h=0$.

The angle the arc subtends is $2\pi/3$, so let’s integrate along $[\pi/2-\pi/3,\pi/2+\pi/3]$ which equals $[\pi/6,5\pi/6]$.

By definition of center of mass,

$$\begin{align}
k &= \frac1M \int y\,dm \\
&= \frac1M \int r\sin(\theta)\, \lambda\,ds \\
&= \frac1M \int r\sin(\theta)\, \lambda r\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{r^2}M \int \lambda\sin(\theta)\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{r^2}{M}\bigl( -\lambda\cos\theta\bigr)\Bigr|^{5\pi/6}_{\pi/6}\\
&= \frac{r^2\lambda}{M}\left[ -\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right) + \cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{r^2\lambda}{M} \left( +\frac{\sqrt3}2 + \frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\\
&= \frac{r^2\lambda\sqrt 3}M=\frac{r^2M\sqrt 3}{LM} = \frac{r^2\sqrt3}{2\pi r/3}\\
&= \frac{3r\sqrt3}{2\pi}\\
&= \frac{9\sqrt3}{2\pi}
\end{align}$$

where $M$ is the mass of the section of arc in question.

Big thanks to David K for spotting the error I had mentioned earlier.

Comment: You should have $L = \frac{2\pi}{3} r$--a larger radius gives a longer arc. With that correction, you get $k=\frac{9\sqrt3}{2\pi},$ which is equal to the other answers when $r = 3.$