# Integrating "moment of inertia" of a fidget-spinner-shape

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, mathematical-physics, polar-coordinates

I'm sorry to ask this once again, but I've explained it with a better explanation.

The problem is,

Calculate "moment of inertia" of a fidget-spinner-shape (blue part).

(radius of a circle is R, and its center is 2R away from the origin.)

I've tried with integration in polar coordinate, but I got stuck in it.

Here is the picture:
[image]

This is where I got stuck:

Let the total mass M

Let's just calculate the part that looks like this

[image]

The polar equation for the circle would be $r^2=4rcos\theta-3$ such that $r=2cos\theta + \sqrt{4(cos\theta)^2 -3}$

so  $\int \int M \frac{rdrd\theta}{AreaColored}r^2$

$r$ is not constant, so we have to put $r$ in.

It is so complicated in this way. I think there could be better ideas.

-----------------------little explanation about the moment of inertia------------------

To calculate the moment of inertia of arbitrary shape,

you have to integrate $dI$ for both $r$ and $\theta$

Basically $dI=dm r^2$  ,  $\int_0^R \int_0^\pi (function) dr d\theta$ in polar coordinates.

If the total mass is M, then $dm=M\frac{(partial-area)}{(total-area)}$

-----------------------------------_---------------------------------------------------

Comment: Let's see the integral you came up with, and exactly where you got stuck.

Comment: @Allawonder ok i will edit

Comment: @Allawonder done editing

Comment: First off, the region is rotationally symmetric of angle $120°.$ So you only need to calculate the integral only for $0<\theta<2π/3.$ The quantity you need is thrice this integral. To ease the integration, you may find the points of tangency of the involved circles. Then split the integral over the range above into three, where by symmetry again the two extreme bits are equal, namely the one you were trying to calculate below.

Comment: Isn't it a hexagon plus three sectors, minus three sectors? All of which have explicit solutions.

Comment: You can get the centroids and moments for [sectors](https://www.efunda.com/math/areas/CircularSection.cfm) and [triangles](https://www.efunda.com/math/areas/triangle.cfm?search_string=triangle%20moment) and combine them by the parallel axis theorem.

Comment: @KeithMcClary This is what I have been looking for! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the figures below, the cross represents the centre of rotation. 
[image][image]

Denote the moment of inertia of the region $S_i$ by $I(S_i)$. The moment of inertia of the fidget spinner is $6I(S_1)+3I(S_4)-6I(S_3)+6I(S_2)$.

Using the parallel axis theorem, it can be deduced that  $I(S_4)=I(S_8)+4MR^2$ and that  $I(S_1)=I(S_7)+MR^2$. It should be obvious that $I(S_6)=I(S_8)/3$.

The center of mass of region $S_5$ is at a distance of $\frac{R}{2\sqrt{2}}$ from the centre of rotation so we can use the parallel axis theorem again to deduce that $I(S_2)=I(S_5)+MR^2((2-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}})^2-1/8)$.

Finally, the distance between the centre of mass of $S_6$ and the centre of rotation [turns out to be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622739/15624) $\frac{3\sqrt3}{2\pi}$. So $I(S_3)=I(S_6)+MR^2((2-\frac{3\sqrt3}{2\pi})^2-\frac{27}{2\pi})$.

Now all we need to do is to find $I(S_8)$, $I(S_5)$, $I(S_7)$, either by calculating them or by [looking them up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia).

As it turns out, $I(S_5)=\frac{5}{12}MR^2$, $I(S_7)=MR^2/4$ and $I(S_8)=MR^2/2$.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for! thanks!!